# Remonter à il y a plus de 3 ans remonter à plus de 3 ans?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

On dit bien « remonter à telle année » (Cette saga remonte à 1994), mais peut-on dire « Cette saga remonte à x ans ou à il y a x ans »?

> Cette saga opposant M. Untel et Mme Unetelle remonte à il y a plus de trois ans/ remonte à plus de trois ans.

Sinon devrais-je plutôt recourir à la formulation « dater de » comme dans:

> « Cette saga opposant M. Untel et Mme Unetelle date de trois ans »?

Pardonnez-moi si je me répète: j’ai comme un souvenir confus d’avoir déjà posé une question relative à ce sujet par le passé sans en être certain. L’anxiété prolongée à laquelle j’ai été en proie tout au long de mon existence a fortement atteint (atrophié) mon hippocampe le temps passant, si bien qu’il a été réduit à un pépin de raisin, d’où mes problèmes de mémoire qui s’ensuivent (autodiagnostic… j’aime bien faire de moi un médecin, cela m’évite bien de l’attente—>je dis n’importe quoi pour me rendre intéressant ou m’ingénier à attirer sur moi la pitié).

Comment: Ça se dit et c'est correct. Quelques exemples parmi d'autres : [Ça remonte à plus de quarante ans d'après ce que j'en sais](https://www.midilibre.fr/2021/01/29/des-archeologues-de-linrap-aident-a-mieux-comprendre-le-passe-local-9339836.php) ; [Ça, ça remonte à il y a plus de 10 ans](https://www.quebecurbain.qc.ca/2009/06/07/la-cite-verte-un-exemple-a-donner/) ; [« L’histoire des arsenaux à Brest, ça remonte à il y a plus de quatre cents ans »](https://www.letelegramme.fr/finistere/brest/naval-group-les-ouvriers-d-etat-ne-lachent-rien-05-07-2018-12018868.php).

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre commentaire faisant office de réponse, None.

Comment: Les exemples sont bien choisis.